# Values getting Skewed?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following cpp code:

```
Pong::Pong()
{
    PongPaddle pp1(0, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 40, 41);
    PongPaddle pp2(320-10, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 38, 39);

    //p1 = (PongPaddle*) malloc(sizeof(PongPaddle));
    //p2 = (PongPaddle*) malloc(sizeof(PongPaddle));
    p1 = &pp1;
    p2 = &pp2;

    Serial.print("X: ");Serial.println((*p1).x);
    Serial.print("Y: ");Serial.println((*p1).y);

    PongBall ppb(240/2, 320/2, 5, p1, p2);
}
```

and the header as:

```
class Pong {
    public:
        Pong();
        void update();
        void draw(Adafruit_TFTLCD tft);
        PongPaddle *p1;
        PongPaddle *p2;
        PongBall *pb;
};
```

PongPaddle has an update class and when it is called its x&y values are not the ones I set, but instead are just random numbers.  My guess is that I have messed up the pointers.  (I tried using malloc and it didn't see to help)

Comment: Even though you commented those lines out, why did you even consider using `malloc` in your C++ code?

Comment: `What do you mean` 1) Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  2) If `PongPaddle` was non-POD, that call to malloc() does not construct objects (read about the difference between `malloc` and `new`).  Why not post the `PongPaddle` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem in your code has been pointed out by Benjamin Lindley's answer. If you must use pointers in `Pong`, change `Pong::Pong` to:

```
Pong::Pong()
{
    p1 = new PongPaddle(0, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 40, 41);
    p2 = new PongPaddle(320-10, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 38, 39);

    Serial.print("X: ");Serial.println((*p1).x);
    Serial.print("Y: ");Serial.println((*p1).y);

    PongBall ppb(240/2, 320/2, 5, p1, p2);
}
```

Please remember that there are pitfalls to using pointers instead of objects in your class. You have to implement:

1. A copy constructor
2. A destructor.
3. An assignment operator

that do the right thing with the pointers `p1` and `p2`.

Refer to [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

**Update, In response to latest comment by OP**

`Pong::Pong()` has to intialize `p1` and `p2` using the right arguments in the initialization list of the constructor. Otherwise, the default constructor will be used. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

```
Pong::Pong() : p1(0, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 40, 41),
               p2(320-10, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 38, 39)
{
    Serial.print("X: ");Serial.println(p1.x);
    Serial.print("Y: ");Serial.println(p1.y);

    PongBall ppb(240/2, 320/2, 5, &p1, &p2);
}
```

Comment: I can't define p1 as so then

class Pong{... PongPaddle p1;}  because it has no type () only type (int, int ...)

Comment: I am suggesting that you keep `PongPaddle* p1;` in your class. Just change the implementation of `Pong::Pong` to allocate objects using the `new` operator and assign them to `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: Fantastic. You've given him a terrible idea, and have him convinced that it is the solution to his problem, and have not even informed him of the potential problems it causes.

Comment: @user3376886 - You're not out of the woods yet.  Your class now needs a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor to handle the dynamically allocated memory.  That's why it was asked whether objects were suitable instead of the pointers.

Comment: Baisically I am making pong and wanna have the main Pong class handle all the other components...

Comment: @user3376886 - How does what you explained mean "I must use pointers"?  It doesn't make any difference anyway, you still need a destructor and copy/assignment functions defined (see the "rule of 3") if you accept this answer.

Comment: How do I make a destructor?  I assume that copy/asignment just creates a clone.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I understand your concern. If the user has a reason to use pointers instead of objects, they must know how to use  pointers properly.

Comment: @RSahu: Isn't it clear that this user *does not* know how to use pointers properly? By the way, your constructor leaks if the second allocation fails, or if something else causes an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @user3376886 That was the main worry. If you don't implement the three other functions that I listed properly, you are going to see strange memory related problems.

Comment: @user3376886 - I think you've just jumped from the frying pan into the fire.  You have not justified why you need pointers.  If you don't use pointers, then none of the issues discussed in this long comment chain come into play.  Instead of trying to get something to compile, investigate *why* using objects is not an option, or *why* using pointers is the only option.

Comment: @user3376886 You initialize `p1` and `p2` in the constructor, `Pong::Pong()`. Not in the header file.

Comment: @user3376886 Of course you can. You just include the header file that contains the definition of `PongPaddle` in the file where `Pong` is defined.

Comment: @user3376886: `PongPaddle` has no default constructor. Which is fine. You just need to initialize them in the initialization list. -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list -- Why didn't you just post a question about that error?

Answer (score 2):

`pp1` and `pp2` are objects local to your `Pong` constructor.  At the end of the constructor, they no longer exist, leaving `p1` and `p2` as dangling pointers.

Why don't you just have `PongPaddle` objects as members, instead of pointers to `PongPaddle` objects?

Comment: If I had them as members and not pointers it won't let me compile because it says there is no type without the input parameters...

Comment: @user3376886: Then you should ask about *that* problem (in another post).

Comment: Can you just tell me here, cause last time they told me to use pointers... Which is why I am where I am...

Is there no way to make those pp1&pp2 stay?

Comment: @user3376886: I could. But I won't. It's a separate question, it belongs in a separate post. Are you having trouble creating another post?

Comment: @user3376886: I can think of various "solutions", but I don't know enough about your situation to know if any of them are correct. I'm not going to give you bad advice just to shut up your compiler.  What is this "last time" you are referring to? Who are "they"? Do you have a link to a previous question?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the long comment chain.  To the OP:  Please look at the code below.  The code below compiles correctly.

First PONGPADDLE.H:

```
#ifndef PONGPADDLE_H
#define PONGPADDLE_H

class PongPaddle 
{
   public:
      PongPaddle(int, int, int, int, int, int);
};
#endif
```

Next PONGBALL.H:

```
#ifndef PONGBALL_H
#define PONGBALL_H

#include "PongPaddle.h"
class PongBall 
{
   PongPaddle p1;
   PongPaddle p2;
   public:
      PongBall(int, int, int, PongPaddle&, PongPaddle&);
};
#endif
```

Next PONG.H:

```
#ifndef PONG_H
#define PONG_H

#include "PongPaddle.h"
#include "PongBall.h"

class Pong {
public:
    Pong();
    PongPaddle p1;
    PongPaddle p2;
    PongBall pb;
};
#endif
```

Now here is PONG.CPP

```
#include "Pong.h"
Pong::Pong() : p1(0, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 40, 41),
               p2(320-10, 240/2 - 5, 10, 40, 38, 39),
               pb(240/2, 320/2, 5, p1, p2)
{
}
```

Note that there are no pointers used whatsoever.  I removed the `Serial` type. Now change the code above into something that doesn't compile that you wish to compile.  Or is this what you're really trying to accomplish?

The other thing missing is the implementation of the constructor for `PongPaddle` and `PongBall`.  But that is implemented in other .CPP files (probably PongPaddle.cpp and PongBall.cpp).